# Change an XML Value in Python

Tags: python, xml

If I have an XML file such as below, how would I be able to change the version from 50 to 51?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <updateCheck seconds="2" />
    <unturnedVersion version="50" />
    <unturnedFolder recoveryBundlesAfterUpdates="false" />
    <rocket useRocket="true" apikey=""/>
    <steam username="" password="" />
    <steamUpdates validate="true" />
    <servers rconEnabled="false">
        <server name="server1" rconPort="27013" rconPassword="pass" />
        <server name="server2" rconPort="27014" rconPassword="pass" />
    </servers>
    <notifyBefore seconds="60" />
</config>
```

I've tried multiple methods to do it, and some don't do anything or it just creates a new version of the unturnedVersion with 51 at the bottom of the code. I want to simply change 50 to 51 or any other value I set.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know if there will always be just 1 instance of unturnedVersion?  If there are multiple, do you want to do this to all of them, or just the first, last, nth, etc.?

Comment: There will just be one instance.

Comment: do you want to go xml or nasty hack-like (text replace)?

Comment: I'd prefer XML, if I couldn't get it to work, I was just going to make a separate file and just leave that version in it so I could just write over it... haha

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). Locate the element via, for example, `find()`, update the `version` attribute through the [`.attrib` dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib) of an element:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <updateCheck seconds="2" />
    <unturnedVersion version="50" />
    <unturnedFolder recoveryBundlesAfterUpdates="false" />
    <rocket useRocket="true" apikey=""/>
    <steam username="" password="" />
    <steamUpdates validate="true" />
    <servers rconEnabled="false">
        <server name="server1" rconPort="27013" rconPassword="pass" />
        <server name="server2" rconPort="27014" rconPassword="pass" />
    </servers>
    <notifyBefore seconds="60" />
</config>"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
unturned_version = root.find("unturnedVersion")
unturned_version.attrib["version"] = "51"

print(ET.tostring(root))
```

Prints:

```
<config>
    <updateCheck seconds="2" />
    <unturnedVersion version="51" />
    <unturnedFolder recoveryBundlesAfterUpdates="false" />
    <rocket apikey="" useRocket="true" />
    <steam password="" username="" />
    <steamUpdates validate="true" />
    <servers rconEnabled="false">
        <server name="server1" rconPassword="pass" rconPort="27013" />
        <server name="server2" rconPassword="pass" rconPort="27014" />
    </servers>
    <notifyBefore seconds="60" />
</config>
```

Note that, if you want to increment the existing version, use:

```
unturned_version.attrib["version"] = str(int(unturned_version.attrib["version"]) + 1)
```

---

And, if you read an XML from file, use `ET.parse()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


tree = ET.parse("input.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
unturned_version = root.find("unturnedVersion")
unturned_version.attrib["version"] = str(int(unturned_version.attrib["version"]) + 1)

print(ET.tostring(root))
```

Comment: Does this work: root = ET.parse(os.path.join(MANAGER_FOLDER, "config_RocketUpdater.xml")) ... I have to read the input from an XML file first. I don't get any errors when I change it to that, but the program doesn't change the value either.

Comment: @AubtinSamai updated with a sample code to read XML from file, works for me.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Just had to add write so it would print to the file.